# Showing that the intersection of these two subspaces is {0}

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

This is something that came up while I was working on a problem. I approached it a little bit differently, and I wanted to see if this approach could work.

We suppose that we have two vector spaces $U$ and $U$ such that $\mbox{dim }U = 3$ and $\mbox{dim }W = 5$. We also assume that $U+W = \mathcal{R}^8$. We want to show that $U \cap W = \{0\}$.

$\underline{Proof}$: Let the list $(u_1,..,u_3)$ be a basis for $U$, and let $(w_1,...,w_5)$ be a basis for $W$.

Consider the sum $U+W = \{a_1u+a_2w: a_1,a_2 \in \mathcal{R} \mbox{ and } u \in U \mbox{and } w \in W\}$. Any vector in this set can be written as a linear combination of vectors from the basis, since by definition all $u$ and $w$ are linear combinations of the basis vectors.

Then we can say that for $v \in U+W, v =\lambda_1u_1+...+\lambda_3u_3+\eta_1w_1+...+\eta_5w_5$

Therefore any vector in the sum $U+W$ can be written as a linear combination of vectors in the list $(u_1,...,u_3,w_1,...,w_5)$ this list must span $\mathcal{R}^8$ as it has length $8$, so therefore it is a basis.

Now here's where I want to get stuck, to show that intersection is $\{0\}$, I want to somehow to be able to say that because this list is linearly independent, then vector that is a combination of the w's (other than the zero vector) could possibly be in the span of the basis for $U$, and vice-versa.

Any help would be appreciated. It seems obvious, but hard to state properly.

Comment: Use the method of contradiction. Assume there is a non zero vector $v$ in $U\cap W$. Then $v$ can be written as a linear combination of $u_i$'s as well as $w_i$'s. This contradicts your result $\{u_1,...,u_3,w_1,...,w_5\}$ is a basis.

Comment: But here you must show that $\{u_1,...,u_3,w_1,...,w_5\}$ is linearly independent to say it is a basis.

Answer (score 3):

We know that $U\cap W$ is a subspace of $\mathcal{R}^8$, correct.  Now let $v \in U\cap W$.  It can certainly be written strictly in terms of the basis vectors of $U$, so $v = a_1u_1 + a_2 u_2  +a_3u_3$ and it is also written in terms of the basis vectors of $W$, so

$$
v = b_1w_1 + \ldots + b_5w_5.
$$

Given the fact that $\{u_1, u_2, u_3, w_1, \ldots, w_5\}$ forms a basis for your space (as you argued above) we then have the $u_i$'s and $w_j$'s are linearly independent.  Therefore the only way we can have

$$
a_1u_1 + a_2 u_2 + a_3u_3 \;\; =\;\; b_1w_1 + \ldots + b_5w_5
$$

is if $a_i = b_j = 0$ for all $i \in \{1,2,3\}$ and $j \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Comment: I believe you mean $a_{i}=b_{j}=0$, not $w_{j}=0$ in the last line.

Comment: @BrianScholl Duly noted, thanks.